# How to select the distinct values of three sql tables and perform inner join with python sqlite3?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I'm trying to perform an inner join of distinct values of three tables from an SQLite DB. I tried multiple times and failed. Please guide me.

Below is a pseudo-code of what I'm trying to achieve

```
sql = ''' 
SELECT DISTINCT lesson_id, question_id FROM lesson_practice_questions as lpq

INNER JOIN 
SELECT DISTINCT topic_id, lesson_id FROM chapter_lessons as cl
WHERE cl.topic_id==2 
ON cl.lesson_id = lpq.lesson_id 

INNER JOIN 
SELECT DISTINCT question_id, subject_id, question_type_id, knowledge_type_ids complexity_level FROM questions as q
ON q.question_id = lpq.question_id;'''

cur.execute(sql)
```

Many Thanks to @eshirvana for taking the time to help out!.

Perfect Solution with ambiguous error resolution for future stackoverflow reference:

```
sql = '''SELECT
    lpq.lesson_id, cl.lesson_id,
    topic_id,
    q.question_id, lpq.question_id,
    subject_id,
    question_type_id,
    knowledge_type_ids,
    complexity
FROM  lesson_practice_questions as lpq
INNER JOIN chapter_lessons as cl on cl.topic_id = 2 and cl.lesson_id = lpq.lesson_id
INNER JOIN questions as q ON q.question_id = lpq.question_id;'''
```

Comment: is it sqlite or mysql? only ag the databse you are using

Comment: Hi, it is SQLITE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the right sql syntax , however you need to provide sample data and desired output if this is not the right output :

```
SELECT
    lpq.lesson_id,
    question_id,
    topic_id,
    lesson_id,
    question_id,
    subject_id,
    question_type_id,
    knowledge_type_ids,
    complexity_level
FROM  lesson_practice_questions as lpq
INNER JOIN chapter_lessons as cl on cl.topic_id = 2 and cl.lesson_id = lpq.lesson_id
INNER JOIN questions as q ON q.question_id = lpq.question_id;
```

Comment: Thank you. Im getting this error: "OperationalError: ambiguous column name: lesson_id". I'll edit the question with screenshots of DB. Thank you!

Comment: @skwolvie use table aliases in he front of column names , like what i did for the first colmn ( see updated asnwer)